# How do I get a list of distinct values for each row in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

In PowerBI, I am struggling to get a concatenate a list of the unique values for each row into a column or a measure. By taking the example of the table below (there are hundreds more rows in a similar style to this):

| Shop | Target |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |
| A | 5 |
| A | 15 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 9 |

I want to write a DAX expression that will give me the following result:

| Shop | Target |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2, 5, 15, |
| B | 1, 9 |

I have tried using the following expression:

`uniqueTarget = CALCULATE(CONCATENATEX(DISTINCT('Table'[Target]),'Table'[Target], ", "))`

But I end up getting a result like this:

| Shop | Target |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2, 5, 15, 1, 9 |
| B | 2, 5, 15, 1, 9 |

I want the list of Targets to be specific to the Shop, but the different DAX functions I have tried either repeat the value (e.g. 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5 etc) or end up giving every single unique value for each shop, as shown above.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Measure = CONCATENATEX(VALUES('Table'[Target]),'Table'[Target], ",")
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7jsufKQ6YU

Comment: Given in the OP’s example they’re getting all targets regardless of the Shop I suspect that they either haven’t got their data model/relationships setup properly OR the Shop field they’re using is from a different table that’s not related to the Target table.

Comment: @Ben was correct - the table I was using came from another table didn't have the relationship set up with the other one and as a result couldn't get the distinct values correctly. After setting up the relationship in the data model, I used David Bacci's answer and it worked!